# Getting a user 's mail server in lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Whats the easiest way of getting the abbreviate name of a users mail mail server, the current user to be specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Function getUserMailServer() As NotesName
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim maildb As New NotesDatabase("", "")
    Call maildb.OpenMail
    Dim nName As NotesName
    Set nName = session.CreateName(maildb.Server)
    Print("Server: " + nName.Abbreviated)
    Set getUserMailServer = nName
End Function
```

`maildb.OpenMail` gives you the mail database of current user.

`maildb.Server` returns the full server name of mail database.

`session.CreateName()` creates a NotesName object from server name.

`nName.Abbreviated` returns the abbreviated server name (same like `maildb.Server`).

Comment: Thanks for your response, If I have to abbreviate this and return it as NotesName, how would that work, Im new to lotus script so if I don't make sense please do correct me

Comment: I changed my answer. I put code in a function which returns the user's email server as NotesName object. This is not just the server name but an object with class properties like `.Abbreviated` or `.Common`. After calling function you can decide what you want to do with result: to store it in a document's names field or to show it in a certain form.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the GetMailInfo method of the NotesDirectory class. This enables you to get the mail-database of every user you specify.

```
mailinfo = notesDirectory.GetMailInfo(username)
```

mailinfo is a Variant containing a String array with the following informations for the specified user:

```
Mail Server - Home mail server for the specified person.
BuildNumber - If getver is true, a string representation of the build number of the specified person's mail server, for example, "303". If getver is false, "".
DominoVersion - If getver is true, a string representation of the Domino version of the specified person's mail server, for example, "Build V80_07042006NP". If getver is false, "".
MailFile - Mail file for the specified person.
ShortName - Short form of the specified person's name.
MailDomain - Notes Domain of the specified person's mail address.
User Name - First entry in the list of user names honored for the specified person.
InternetMailAddress - Internet mail address for the specified person.
OutOfOffice - Out of Office service type. "1" indicates Agent, "2" indicates Service.
```

See IBM help [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETMAILINFO_METHOD_DIRECTORY.html) for more information.

Comment: Please can you add the link for the IBM help. Makes your answer even better.

Comment: I have again edited your answer. Have a look in edit mode and that's how Urls should be added. Hope this helps in your future posts.